# how to write a c++ code to make function that returns true if initial as an argument is capital, returns false if not

Tags: c++

I want to write a program to  make function that returns true if initial as an argument is capital, returns false if not.
what does it mean for inital as an argument 
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
bool IsUpper (char);   

int main ( ) {
    char ch;
    cout << "Enter a letter: " ; 
    cin >> ch ;

    if (IsUpper (ch)) 
       cout << ch << " is a  capital " << endl;
    else 
       cout << ch << " is not a capital " << endl;

    return 0;
}

bool IsUpper(char ch) {

{
    if ((ch >= 'A' ) && (ch <= 'Z'))
       return true;
   else 
      return false; 
}

     return false;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: Have a look at [`std::isupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code you can replace :

```
bool IsAVowel (char ch) {
{
   if ((ch >= 'A' ) && (ch <= 'Z'))
     return true;
    else 
     return false; 
}
```

by

```
bool isUpper(const char ch) {
  return (ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z');
}
```

Comment: sir what does it mean by intial as an argument does it mean first letter must be capital or whole letter must be capital?

Comment: Using the overload of `std::isupper` from `locale` instead of checking that the character is within the interval [A-Z] keeps the _locale_ separate from the program code. This is an important step to support internationalization. See [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed054768fc3b9e71)

Comment: @ComeRaczy yes, best pratice.